# In Sitecore 7.2 file upload ,the path is coming as media\test\abc.pdf instead of media/test/abc.pdf

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I am trying to add one file from file directory in directory.
While I am clicking on +(insert file) the and selecting a file from directory the path is formed as  media\test\abc.pdf  instead of media/test/abc.pdf.
Even though chrome is able to resolve the url Firefox is not.

Comment: Post up some code of how you are rendering the link to the media item. Sounds like you either need to use a control or [use the MediaLinkManager](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/sitecore-links-with-linkmanager-and-mediamanager/) to generate the URL link.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're using a physical file path that you're getting the backslash. One of the simplest things you can do is a string.Replace() expression to make every backslash a forward slash.

Not sure what your specific use case is, or how much work it would be, but if you're going to use the path on the web and your PDF is located in the MediaLibrary, it might be worth looking into using the URL property of the Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem object.